Is there a method for using Photoshop .abr brushes within grease pencil?
Tutorials I found aren't clear on how to import them. I tried using converted PNGs, but the color of the stroke stays white and looks bad.
Straightforward steps on how to do this would be very helpful!



I haven't used Photoshop before and I can't seem to find a good tutorial that shows how to do it so I can honestly say just try importing it as every option Blender has and see if that works. Have you tried svg or jpg?
